# How to delete first&last characters ... but just numbers

Tags: text

I have 10000 sites of text and basically it is subtitle-text... I want to delete of every line the last **5 numbers** and the **first 2** numbers without touching/changing the text...

Here is an example:

> **18:**      00:03:13:05 00:03:16:17 **03:12** Moi, j'aurais mis ça à la même hauteur que ça.
>
> **19:**      00:03:18:02 00:03:21:05 **03:03** Dans un premier temps, je termine.
>
> **20:**      00:03:23:15 00:03:26:07 **02:17** Ah, toujours le travail !

The bold numbers should be deleted.

Comment: If you have the text present on your local machine, then you can open it using a good text editor, like sublime, or vim, and then use find and replace with appropriate regular expressions to achieve this.

Comment: great aseem ray baranwal. I will try with sublime. do you know the "appropriate" expressions to achieve?

Comment: See here: http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_overview.html#regular-expressions My example combined with the Sublime docs should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you can approach this.

1. Split the string into substrings and then concatenate the ones you want.
2. Regular Expression to pull backrefs out of the text.

Since your data seems pretty normalized, and is essentially space delimited, you could tokenize the string based on a space, and then put the 2nd, 3rd, and "rest" back together, throwing away the 1st and 4th token.

You don't say what tools or languages you want to use, but in Java you might use [public String[] split(String regex, int limit)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

With Vim, something like `:0,$s/\d\+: //` should remove the first part. A pattern like `:0,$s/ \d\d:\d\d / /` should remove the second part.

Comment: thank you jdv

Actueally I was searching for a simple script-solution with "find & replace" in World or a similar,easy way...

Comment: If you mean "Word" I have no idea, but most text editors will allow you to construct a pattern as per the comment by Aseem Raj Baranwal.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all lines in the file are the same and you have a fixed width file, on a UNIX like system (Unix, Linux, Mac, FreeBSD) , you can try

```
cut -b 1-4,28-33 --complement INPUTFILENAME > OUTPUTFILENAME
```

If not, you should be able to do this in two steps, as follows:

```
cut -d : -f 1 --complement INPUTFILENAME > OUTPUTFILENAME
cut -b 24-29 --complement OUTPUTFILENAME > OUTPUTFILENAME
```

The second solution's first step deletes the first number identifier field regardless of its length. The second step changes what should then be lines of similar width (for the columns of interests).

Comment: I was assuming that there will be lines like "100: ..." so the field positions will no longer match up.

Comment: @jdv good point. That makes it much trickier unless it is a fixed width file, which it probably is not.

A possible work around is to do it in two steps, as I show in the edited answer.